# Override a Global Filter in MVC for One Method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

In my filterConfig, I have registered a global attribute filter, which requires authorization on each of my methods.

However, I have one particular method where I want to apply a different authorization filter attribute. How does one accomplish this, if at all possible?

Note: I do not want to use the [AllowAnonymous] attribute (which works seamlessly and completely ignores my filter), since I want the request to be authorized, just through a different set of authorization logic on the method.

Comment: I haven't dealt with filters, but will this work? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7(v=vs.71).aspx I use location elements to bypass authorization on a few pages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can alter your filter to allow multiple by setting `AllowMultiple = true` in the `AttributeUsage` attribute on your attribute class, and add a check so that if the filter is present multiple times, the globally-applied one doesn't execute. The `ActionExecutingContext` that gets passed into `OnActionExecuting()` lets you get the filters applied via `filterContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes()`, so you can use that here.

Then, alter the constructor so that you can pass in a parameter (probably an enum) that it can use to decide which authorisation method to use - the normal one, or this other one. Give that parameter a default value that makes it select the normal auth method. Then, on that one method that needs a different auth method, you can apply the filter with the other value of the parameter. So it might look like this:

```
public class CustomAuthAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public CustomAuthAttribute(AuthMethod method = AuthMethod.StandardAuth)
    {
        //stuff
    }
}

[CustomAuth(AuthMethod.WeirdAuth)]
public ActionResult MethodThatNeedsDifferentAuth()
{
    //stuff
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without modifying the original CustomAttribute I created?

Comment: And still be able to pass a value into it? Erm... well I guess you could inherit from that original version and add the extra constructor, and then override the methods from the base version, do your logic that selects one auth method or the other, and then when you want to trigger the logic from the original version you can call `base.Authorize()` or whichever method it is.

Comment: @anaximander can you post the code about how to check the check so the globally applied one doesnt execute

Answer (score 3):

you can write your own version of the authorize attribute and pass specific parameter to depending on what action would you like your attribute to do for example

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
   {
        public string currentAction { get; set; }
        public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
           if (currentAction != "notallowed")
            {
                HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
            }
        }
    }

 protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext context)
    {
        context.Result = new RedirectResult("/home/login");
    }
```

and then apply it to your class or action

```
[CustomAuthorize(currentAction = "notallowed")]
public class HomeController : Controller
```

Comment: I use this with Web API 2 - but I needed to add     [OverrideAuthorizationAttribute] to the controller